# jinja2: sort dict by defined key order?

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

So lets say I want to display some data like this:

```
• b is foo
• a is bar
• c is baz
```

...but my dataset looks like this (or any other order, since JSON doesn't care):

```
{
"a": "bar",
"b": "foo",
"c": "baz"
}
```

How do I tell Jinja2 to display my data with keys always in `b a c` order)?  And what if I'm not sure if the element `c` will always be present?

I thought it would be something like this, to no avail:

```
<ul>
{% for key, value in my_dict.items()|dictsort(by=['b', 'a']) %}
    <li>{{ key }} is {{ value }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could loop through a hard-coded list of keys:

```html
<ul>
{% for key in ('b', 'a', 'c') %}
    {% if key in my_dict %}
    <li>{{ key }} is {{ my_dict[key] }}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Non-existing keys are handled by the `if` test.

Comment: I think this is getting there.  The trouble is, and maybe I should amend my question, is that there may well be elements `d e f g ...` which I can't ignore.  Can I "pop" `a` and  `b` from the dictionary, and fall back to a default representation for others which are not covered by the hard-coded loop?

Comment: @niteshade: you can *skip* `a` and `b` in the loop and explicitly list those first, perhaps? Or you can create a list for the keys (`list(my_dict)`) and manipulate that, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Python dicts are not ordered, maybe you can use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from collections :

```
import collections

my_dict = {
    "a": "bar",
    "b": "foo",
    "c": "baz"
}
my_ord_dict = collections.OrderedDict(my_dict)
```

Comment: I considered this, but unfortunately I have to deal with a pretty rigid, and unpredictable, API.